# JGraphx Graph Editor with Initial Vertex

Tags: java, graph, jgraphx

I'm Customizing **jgraphx graph editor** example program. In the graph editor program we can add the vertex to the graph by drag and drop icon from the palette. But i need to add a **initial vertex** to the graph that means, In the initial[New] graph editor frame the graph editor's graph should contain one vertex. How can I add a initial vertex to the graph without drag and drop from a palette?.

Comment: if you have access to the graph you should just be able to call `graph.insertVertex()` with some params. you can search for an example in the [documentation] (https://jgraph.github.io/mxgraph/docs/manual_javavis.html)

Answer (score 1):

If you have the jgraphx project checked out, in the GraphEditor try using the insertVertex method in the constructor as follows:

```
public GraphEditor(String appTitle, mxGraphComponent component)
{
    super(appTitle, component);
    final mxGraph graph = graphComponent.getGraph();
    graph.insertVertex(graph.getDefaultParent(), null, "Test", 100, 100, 200, 100);
    ...
}
```

This should give you a vertex to start from